# What is the derivative of $\phi _i\left(x\right)=\prod _{j=0,\:j\ne \:i\:}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$ for i=0,...,n?

Tags: calculus

I got:

$$\sum _{k=0,\:k\ne \:i}^n\:\left(\frac{\left(x-x_k\right)'\cdot \prod ^n_{j=0,\:j\ne \:k}\left(x-x_j\right)}{\prod _{l=0,\:l\ne \:i}^n\left(x-x_l\right)}\right)$$

But is it right?

Comment: When in doubt, try your formula out for a small test-case, for example $n=1$.

Comment: You can suppress $(x-x_k)'=1$...

Comment: Why? Shouldnt it be equal to -x_k?

Comment: No, for example $(x-3)'=1$...

Comment: O sry you're right